Graphing perpendicular lines
Consider the following MWE:
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis lines=middle,
        xlabel={$x$},
        ylabel={$y$},
        xmin=-3, xmax=9,
        ymin=-5, ymax=25,
        samples=100,
        domain=-3:9,
        legend pos=north west,
        grid=both,
        grid style={line width=.1pt, draw=gray!10},
        major grid style={line width=.2pt, draw=gray!50},
        minor tick num=1,
    ]
        \addplot[red, thick] {(8 - x)/2};
        \addlegendentry{$x + 2y = 8$}

        \addplot[blue, thick] {2*x + 5};
        \addlegendentry{$y = 2x + 5$}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

How can I make it so that the lines look perpendicular? Probably it is the scale. Also, can you help me review the code and check for compatibility issues to the current pgfplots package?
I would like for it to resemble the output from Geogebra.


Add axis equal or axis equal image on axis keys.

Thanks, that seems to address the issue but can you assist me a little further. I updated the question.

Sure! GeoGebra has an option to export the current canvas to tikz code! Have you tried it?
